# Submenu not overlapping the side parent elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created custome side bar for my site, All is fine but I have menu's and submenu's when user hovers on the menu list if it has the submenu then it will show 
thats fine. The problem is submenu not overlapping the scrollbar and side parent/sibling element. I have added images here for more clarification.

```css
.menu {
    height: 100%;
    width:16.16% !important;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    left: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
    background-color: white;    
    border-right:2px solid #f1f1f1;
}

.menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left:-40px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu ul > div{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:18px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #f1f1f1;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu ul li {
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height:auto;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom:1px solid #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-left:10px;
}
.menu ul ul{
    min-height: 30px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    left: 80%;
    top:100%;
    border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
    z-index: -1000000;
}

.menu ul ul > li{
    width: 250px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.menu > ul > li > div > i{
    float: right;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
.menu ul li:hover{
    background-color:#cccccc;
    cursor:pointer;
    opacity: 1;
}
.menu ul li:hover > ul{
    opacity: 2;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 100000000;
    //left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-----Header will come here ----->
<div class="container-fluid row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center" id="topHeader">
        <span>Circulation</span>
    </div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="menu"><i id="hideSideBar" class="fa fa-close"></i>
        <ul class="menuList"><div class="listName">Reports</div>
            <li class="path" data-screen="CustomizedCirculationReportsCt/index" id="li_CustomizedReport">Customized Report</li>
            <li class="path" data-screen="CustomizedCirculationStatisticsCt/index" id="li_CustomizedReport">Customized Statistics</li>
            <li class="hasChildUl" id=""><div class="listName">UserWise Report<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></div>
                <ul class="menuList">
                    <li class="path" data-screen="UserWiseCirculationController/AllUserCirculation" id="userWiseCrReport">Circulation Report</li>
                    <li class="path" data-screen="UserWiseCirculationController/userWiseFineCollection" id="userWiseFineCrReport">Fine Collection Report</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10 firstChild">
    <div class="row">
        <p>Web pages goes here</p>
    </div>
</div>
<!-----Footer will come here ----->
```

Image :
[image: I want to overlap the hidden part of the submenu.]

Answer (score 0):

### Updated Answer

I found a [nice article on Popping out of hidden overflows](https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/) that seems to address the issue.

The problem is due to non-obvious behaviour of the combined `overflow` properties and nested view hierarchies from `position: absolute/relative/fixed`.

You need a non-overflowing parent element that acts as the positioning anchor for the sub-menus. I tried to strip down your example to the neccessary parts:

```css
.menu {
    position: fixed;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 100px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border: 1px dashed #ccc;
}

.menu ul li {
    /*
      this seems to be the problematic property
      position: relative;
    */
}

.menu ul ul {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 80%;
    background: red;
}

.menu ul li:hover {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

.menu ul li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Customized Report
            <ul>
                    <li>Circulation Report</li>
                    <li>Fine Collection Report</li>
                </ul></li>
            
            <li>Customized Statistics</li>
            <li>Customized Statistics</li>
            <li>Customized Statistics</li>
            <li>Customized Statistics</li>
            <li>Customized Statistics</li>
            <li>Customized Statistics</li>
            <li>Customized Statistics</li>
            <li>UserWise Report
                <ul>
                    <li>Circulation Report</li>
                    <li>Fine Collection Report</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

But there is a problem with the positioning of the submenu which can be addressed with javascript. Check the article for a better explanation.

Personally I always try to avoid nested scrolling whereever I can. I suggest that you evaluate the possibility of scrolling the whole page when the menu grows. Also, I'd not rely on submenus that are shown by `:hover` or `mouseover` because they are not available on touch-controlled browsers.

### Original Answer

In the CSS, the menu has set its [horizontal overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) to hidden. The Popup-Menu will show up when you remove the overflow properties:

```
.menu {
    height: 100%;
    width:16.16% !important;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    left: 0;
    /* 
      Remove this props

      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: auto;
    */
    padding-bottom: 10%;
    background-color: white;    
    border-right:2px solid #f1f1f1;
}
```

It works when you remove those lines from your example code.

Comment: but I want overflow-y for scrolling because menu will grow.